# Calling Meteor method on server returns before function is complete

Tags: meteor

I am calling a method on the server with this code:

```
Meteor.call 'getTitle', post.url, (error, title) ->
  console.log 'client side title is: ' + title
```

and on the server:

```
Meteor.methods
  getTitle: (url) ->
    fullURL = addhttp(url)
    read fullURL, (err, article, meta) ->
      if err
        console.log err
        err
      else
        console.log article.title
        article.title
```

And on the client the return value is undefined. I want it to return the article.title value from the read function. Because once the read function is called it keeps going and does not wait for the callback with the return data. To see this clearly if I modify the function to include a return value below the read function the return value is sent correctly.

```
Meteor.methods
  getTitle: (url) ->
    fullURL = addhttp(url)
    read fullURL, (err, article, meta) ->
      if err
        console.log err
        err
      else
        console.log article.title
        article.title
    return 'this return value is sent!'
```

But how can I call this method, and have it return the value that is in the callback from the read function (article.title)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use futures.

```
@Future = Npm.require('fibers/future')
```

then:

```
Meteor.methods
  getTitle: (url) ->
    ...
    fut = new Future()
    doSomething ->
      ...
      fut.return {success: true}
    fut.wait()
```